# App installation error : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-manifest

When I try to run my flutter app on my phone, I get this error

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\kavis\OneDrive\Desktop\New 
folder\care_receiver_app\ss_carereceiver_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: 
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: 
/data/app/vmdl378681921.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #26): 
com.owaslo.sukithasagayo.carereceiver.mainActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) 
requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are 
present]
Error launching application on Pixel 6.
```

I read many other questions about it here but I didn't find a solution so far, could anyone have a look at my manifest and tell me what I did wrong?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.owaslo.sukithasagayo.carereceiver">
<application
    android:label="Sukitha Sagayo"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Below is a screenshot of the file structure
[image]
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 6):

Under this line `android:name=".MainActivity"` , add another line like this

```
android:exported="true"
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: doesnot working . any other solutions